# Is there any way to log all the icefaces logs?

Tags: jsf, icefaces

Our view layer are made from JSF 2.1.4,Icefaces 3.3.When we are starting our application we are able to see all the logs in eclipse console is there any way to log all the icefaces logs into a file .

```
# configure the ice-faces logging
 log4j.appender=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender 
 log4j.appender.File=D:/icefaces.log
 log4j.appender.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout 
 log4j.appender.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%p] %c:%L - %m%n

 log4j.appender.com.icesoft.faces.application.D2DViewHandler=FINEST 
 log4j.appender.com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener=FINEST
 log4j.appender.org.icepush=FINEST
 log4j.appender.org.icepush.application.PushRenderer=FINEST
 log4j.appender.org.icepush.application.PortableRenderer=FINEST
 log4j.appender.org.icefaces=FINEST
```

I have added the above code in my log4j.properties file, but it is not working I got from [here](http://www.icesoft.org/JForum/posts/list/21305.page#sthash.fHPDRlrU.dpbs) here it is doing console appender, but I want FileAppender. Without specifying anything how it will decide what to log e.g I have configured other logs and it is logging, in the log4j.properties I have mentioned like

```
log4j.appender.defalut=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.defalut.File=D:/xyz.log
log4j.appender.defalut.MaxFileSize=20MB
log4j.appender.defalut.MaxBackupIndex=5
log4j.appender.defalut.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.defalut.layout.conversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%p] %c:%L - %m%n
```